# Crop an image to make it circle shaped

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, icons

I know that for doing this it must be used `border-radius: 50%` but it seems to not work in my case.

I'm using React/JSX notation, this is the icon:

```
<i style={{ borderRadius: '50%' }} className="big cc visa icon" />
```

Unfortunately, `style` does not crop the image as I would expect. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Check this, It might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop

Comment: Show us what that classes do. But my bet is that you are missing the display:block.

Comment: What styles are applied to the image if you look at the page in dev tools?

Comment: @DarshShah I don't really see a way to create a circle-shaped image with that library... I only see how to crop it into a rectangle.

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamez If you check the props section in docs then you will find a prop named `circularCrop` with shows the crop area as a circle.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is more of an CSS issue than a react issue.

The  element is set to `display: inline` by default. To change this you would need to set it to `display: block` and define width and height. To do this inline in react you could use something like this:

```
      <i
        style={{
          borderRadius: "50%",
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          background: "red",
          display: "block"
        }}
        className="big cc visa icon"
      />
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-https-9q50j?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it does something but not what I was expecting. here is a screenshot of the result: https://i.imgur.com/Md9r8nJ.png

Comment: Can you share the css where the background image is defined? Or is it an actual element inside the <i>? Also how exactly do you want it to be? Cropping the image? Or displaying it in the center with a background color?

Comment: it is just that <i> element. I want to crop the image and show it circle shaped instead of rectangle

Comment: Can you share the css that is shown when you inspect the element with the developer tool in firefox/chrome/safari?

Comment: If it is a background image you can use background size and position like in the codesandbox. I updated it: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-https-9q50j?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your i has display block css property and size. Then you can do the cropping with border radius. Position and size of image inside, you can manage by background-sizing and other properties.

Here is example in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-lichterman-9rwmh?